# Using R with ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, r, spatstat

I've used the integration of [R](http://www.r-project.org/) with QGIS, and found it a very uesful tool. Having taken a look at the R toolbox [extension for 9](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=16444) and the [extension for 10](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=F855D6D1-1422-2418-A0B2-643E624A8925) it appears they both offer only point clustering to demonstrate the proof of concept.

Can other analysis methods available in R be implemented in ArcGIS Desktop through a python script (for example, implementing specific parts of the [spatstat](http://www.csiro.au/resources/Spatial-Point-Patterns-in-R.html) package)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is now an [R-ArcGIS Community on Github](https://r-arcgis.github.io/) that offers:

- r-bridge-install to:

> Install the R ArcGIS Tools

- r-bridge:

> Bridge library to connect ArcGIS and R, including `arcgisbinding` R
>   library

- r-sample-tools:

> Sample tools illustrating R usage in geoprocessing scripts

Answer (score 7):

The [Geospatial Modelling Environment](http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/) (the successor of Hawth's Tools for ArcGIS) links python scripting, R and ArcGIS in a useful way. I haven't investigated the links with R in detail, but it looks like it may be useful for what you're trying to do.

If you're trying to do something yourself then [StatCONN](http://rcom.univie.ac.at/) may be useful.

Answer (score 3):

I extended [Mark Janikas' work](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=F855D6D1-1422-2418-A0B2-643E624A8925) on interfacing R and ArcGIS.

Specifically, I built an ["R script to ArcGIS Toolbox converter."](http://ifgibox.de/g_carr02/Interfacing_R_and_ArcGIS_with_Python.pdf) The user writes an annotated R script and loads it to an ArcMap add-in, which generates a ToolBox for the R script. The ToolBox can be used to load results to ArcMap.

This is the work flow:

[image]

And this is how the ArcMap add-in looks like:

[image]

[image]

Compared to the Mark Janikas' work, **my approach avoids two steps** for R users wanting to share their work:

- Defining a toolbox from scratch in ArcToolbox (where each parameter has to be set by hand)
- Creating a Python script with the logic of the created toolbox, so the user doesn't have to know anything about Python.

Look at [this video](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xpsqma_interfacing-r-and-arcgis-through-python_tech) to get a better idea.

Comment: You know that Mark's scripts are depreciated, correct? The logistic function calls two depreciated functions and the cluster tool relies on a package that no is no longer maintained and as such, is not available at R >= 3.0.0. Given that R is at 3.1.2, users will likely get nothing but errors when running through your example. I have rewritten these scripts with several notable improvements including an autologistic model and silhouette optimization using a K-medoids clustering algorithm. If you would like the scripts, let me know and I will aim you to the download.

Comment: I took Mark Janikas' script just for the sake of comparing both approaches, his and mine, through a common example. I expect users use their own R scripts (they would need to annotate them first) to experiment and take advantage of my add-in. Thanks anyway for your offer.