# Using R with ArcGIS for Desktop (without using GME)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, r, spatial-statistics

I am trying to learn R generally and making statistics for maps. I found some useful tricks for making maps with it but it is not the best you can do. My everyday GIS program is ArcGIS.  How I can use R in ArcGIS?  A tool I use is the GME plugin. Is this the only way?

I tried to use R in QGIS but a plugin I found never worked.

Comment: Also: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1336/using-r-with-arcgis-desktop

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Regarding R in general I'd really recommend having a look at  [Applied Spatial Data Analysis with R](http://www.asdar-book.org/) book. It offers very good introduction to spatial concepts within R framework. And webpage provides lots of code snippets and data to practice what you read about.

Regarding coupling R and ArcGIS specifically, Python is one of the options here. Have a look at [these](http://proceedings.esri.com/dvd/uc/2009/uc/tws/workshops/tw_940.ppt) [two](http://proceedings.esri.com/dvd/uc/2010/uc-index/uc/workshops/tw_664.ppt) presentations for general overview.

There are [some](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=6163F094-1422-2418-8881-1B80A9665E36) [tools](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=F855D6D1-1422-2418-A0B2-643E624A8925) and a [walk-trough](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002w0000007w000000.htm) provided by ESRI Resource Center that might be good starting point for developing your own projects.

You might also want to run your geoprocessing scripts from within R with [RPyGeo](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RPyGeo/index.html) package.

Comment: I extended [Mark Janikas' work](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=F855D6D1-1422-2418-A0B2-643E624A8925), cited by radek. Specifically, I built an ["R script to ArcGIS ToolBox converter"](http://ifgibox.de/g_carr02/Interfacing_R_and_ArcGIS_with_Python.pdf) The user writes an annotated R script, loads it through an ArcMap add-in, which generates a Toolbox for the R script. The ToolBox can be used to load results to ArcMap. Look at [this video](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xpsqma_interfacing-r-and-arcgis-through-python_tech) to get a better idea.

Comment: @radek Do you know if the RPyGeo package is working in ArcGIS 10.2.2? I couldn't make it work!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure of the specific interaction you're looking for between a GIS GUI and R, but I'll mention a couple of seemingly relevant options:

- [A Practical Guide to Geostatistical Mapping](http://spatial-analyst.net/book/) covers moving fluidly between R, SAGA GIS and Google Earth for analyzing complex geostatistical problems.
- The [spgrass6](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spgrass6/index.html) package allows interaction between GRASS data and R, which likewise can be accessed in QGIS via the QGIS GRASS plugin.

Comment: Yes, I know about this guide and I think it's very useful. However, I had some difficulties and when I asked them for help they didn't respond.

Answer (score 1):

There is a an existing standalone tool called [GeoDa](http://geodacenter.asu.edu/projects/opengeoda) that enables analysis of spatial data using R (and it displays the spatial data within the program). I haven't used it recently, but previously you could install certain packages to perform analysis.

I've also seen some very nice spatial analysis using the [ggplot2](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/) package.

Comment: GeoDa is its own software independent of the R stats package. But that same center did create the spdep package for R and maintains tutorials on using that package in R (along with other tutorials on spatial regression in general and using GeoDa). Link here, http://geodacenter.asu.edu/learning/tutorials

Comment: It has been some time since I used it, but I thought you could also add additional R packages to Geoda. I updated my answer to clarify that it is standalone (and I realize it is a slightly tangential answer to the posters original question).

Comment: You can't add R libraries to GeoDa, but the spdep R library does have the ability to read gal neighbor files produced by GeoDa. You can do everything in R that you can in GeoDa, but GeoDa is nice for its interactive brushing/linking/visualization and everything is GUI based. Even if your only interested in R the tutorials for GeoDa are worth to read just for an intro to spatial regression modelling.