# Using rpy2 in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, r, rpy2

I have a 3rd party python geoprocessing script that requires [`rpy2`](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2.html), and thus also [r](/questions/tagged/r). What is the best way to get these working together?

[Using R with ArcGIS Desktop](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1336/using-r-with-arcgis-desktop) says the most useful option for using R with ArcGIS is via the [Geospatial Modelling Environment](http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/) but as near as I can tell GME doesn't use rpy2. The script I'd like to use is not that large, but I didn't write it and don't want to port it to a different module. I don't understand the workings well enough to be confident I could do so without making a mistake.

Answer (score 3):

The script should work if you have R and rpy2 installed properly. First install R, then rpy2, and be sure that you update your PATH with the rpy2 location.

See: http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-dev/html/overview.html#installation

Depending how explicit the third-party script is in importing the rpy2 module you may need to set the RHOME path thusly:

```
from rpy_options import set_options
set_options(RHOME='C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-2.13.1\\')
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on how you managed to install rpy2? Getting errors during installation.

Answer (score 2):

Installing rpy2 in windows can be rather complex. Here are the instructions that worked for me:

```
1. Install R
------------
http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/


2. Install Rtools
-----------------
http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/


3. Define environmental variables
---------------------------------
Control Panel | Advanced tab | Environmental Variables

define the following: RHOME, R_HOME, R_USER

examples
~~~~~~~~ 
RHOME: C:\Program Files\R\R-2.13.1
R_HOME: C:\Program Files\R\R-2.13.1
R_USER: C:\Users\username\Documents


4. Append path to R (and Rtools) executable(s) to PATH
------------------------------------------------------
Control Panel | Advanced tab | Environmental Variables

example paths: C:\Program Files\R\R-2.13.1\bin\i386; C:\Rtools\bin


5. Build rpy2
-------------
1. Download and execute the binary executable 

or 

2. Download the source and build:

In the rpy2 folder...

python setup.py build --force -c mingw32
python setup.py install
```

Adapted from https://bitbucket.org/lgautier/rpy2/pull-request/3/added-some-win32-install-instructions